# Fortran read statement's iostat parameter returning code 5001

Tags: io, fortran, gfortran

I am working on a small code in fortran that calculates BMI, but I have one issue with iostat parameter of the read statement. The whole code follows:

```
program calculate_bmi
  ! Simple BMI calculator
  implicit none
  character :: unit_system
  character :: height_unit*15, weight_unit*10
  real :: height, weight, bmi
  integer :: ierror


  print *, 'Would you like to use imperial or metric system?'
  systemloop: do
    print *, 'Press [I] for imperal system or press [M] for metric system.'
    read *, unit_system
    if (unit_system == 'i' .or. unit_system == 'I' .or. &
     unit_system == 'm' .or. unit_system == 'M') exit systemloop
  end do systemloop

  if (unit_system == 'i' .or. unit_system == 'I') then
    height_unit='inches'
    weight_unit = 'pounds'
  else
    height_unit = 'centimeters'
    weight_unit= 'kilograms'
  end if

  print *, 'Type in your height in ', height_unit
  read (*, iostat = ierror) height
  if (ierror /= 0) then
    print *, 'Invalid input for height!'
    call exit
  end if
  print *, 'Type in your weight in ', weight_unit
  read (*, iostat = ierror) weight
  if (ierror /= 0) then
    print *, 'Invalid input for weight!'
    call exit
  end if

  if (unit_system == 'i' .or. unit_system == 'I') then
    bmi = 703 * weight / (height**2)
  else
    bmi = weight / ((height/100)**2)
  end if

  print *, 'Your BMI is: '
  write (*, 1) NINT(bmi*10)/10.0
  1 format(f6.1)
end program calculate_bmi
```

The problem occurs at this block of code:

```
 print *, 'Type in your height in ', height_unit
  read (*, iostat = ierror) height
  if (ierror /= 0) then
    print *, 'Invalid input for height!'
    call exit
  end if
  print *, 'Type in your weight in ', weight_unit
  read (*, iostat = ierror) weight
  if (ierror /= 0) then
    print *, 'Invalid input for weight!'
    call exit
  end if
```

The iostat always returns 5001 as a code, and the read statement doesn't await for input and just terminates the program. I did some Google-ing but couldn't really figure out what exactly is the problem. If I remove the iostat from the read statement, the code works just fine, but in that case I have nothing in the way of error handling and prevention of bad input.

I am a bit new to fortran, so please let me know where I made the mistake. Also I am using Gfortran as my compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read statement would normally require two positional arguments, one for the input unit (or `*` to declare it to be the standard input) and one for the format (or, again, `*` to figure it out on itself).

Without parenthesis, i.e. with

```
read *, some_var
```

the command automatically defaults to the standard input stream, so the single `*` is just for the format. But once you use parentheses, you need to declare both the input unit and the format.

The `read` statement, as well as `open`, `close`, and `write`, have for some while now supported an `iomsg` parameter, which is a character string and gives a human readable explanation to the error.

Try modifying it like this:

```
character(len=100) :: ioerrmsg
...
read (*, *, iostat=ioerror, iomsg=ioerrmsg) weight
if (ioerror /= 0) then
    print *, "Encountered Error:"
    print *, ioerrmsg
    call exit
end if
```

This should give you some hints on what's going on.

Cheers

PS: If someone knows how long the `iomsg` string is by default, please let me know in the comments. But length 100 usually works for me.

Comment: I feel so stupid that it is a parameter that I missed out on. Thank you very much for your answer and the explanation, it solved the problem!

Comment: It doesn't matter how long the message string is.  What matters is the length of the variable that receives it.  `iomsg=str` will either pad or truncate the sting to fit in `str`

Comment: @evets Yes, but I would like to know the shortest length of the `iomsg` parameter so that it won't be truncated. It's not urgent, but I would like to know.

Comment: @chw21, I don't think that there is a portable answer as the Fortran standard does mandate the length of `iomsg` values.  OTOH, it seems compiler writers tend to be terse with error messages.  For practical purposes, I suspect you can get away with a string with a length of 128.